# Should "two-week" be hyphenated in "a two-week all-expense-paid trip"?

Tags: hyphenation, compounds, determiners

Which is correct — "a two-week all-expense-paid trip" or "a two week all-expense-paid trip"?

Answer (score 0):

A better phrasing would be:

> *A [two-week](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1314&dat=19460712&id=aSxWAAAAIBAJ&sjid=OuUDAAAAIBAJ&pg=6696,3098928) [all-expense](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all-expense) trip.*

It should be "two-week" in careful English, though the unhyphenated alternative is also acceptable in slacker prose.